# Accessing locations in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays

For my app I will need to access different town and store data for each town. Basically it will be a 2d array with one dimension being the town and the next the data. I was just wondering (using Xcode and Objective C) how I could access every town in a country (I'm looking at the UK if that helps). I don't need it on a map I just need it so people can store data relative to their town simply by searching for the town and adding their data to the array for that town. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it. If you want to use the user's device GPS to identify its location, than you can use the [Google Places API that you can install through cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GooglePlaces)

If you want to perform a search, you can obtain a API key from Google and then use their URL based search. For example, this URL should return a list of Starbuks in Seattle. There are more parameters that can be set and can apply to your case.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=starbucks+seattle&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```